# access multiple values against 1 duplicating key

Tags: python

I have 2 columns.

```
RAB10   -0.016575
MEF2C   -0.019655
SP2 1.24E-01
SP2 -0.18870625
SP2 0.0879425
```

I want output like

```
RAB10   -0.016575
MEF2C   -0.019655
SP2 1.24E-01
    -0.18870625
    0.0879425
```

For repeating keys I can get just 1 key and all corresponding values.

I wrote this code for it:

```
import math
import numpy
import csv
import collections
from decimal import *
from collections import defaultdict
with open('output.csv','rb') as file:
  contents = csv.reader(file)
  #storing content of Common genes Result edited file in matrix
  matrix = list()
  for row in contents:
    matrix.append(row)

#to get both the index and the item
for index, item in enumerate(matrix):
#to access 2nd column value
   first_column = [ row[0] for row in matrix ]
   second_column = [ row[1] for row in matrix
for q, a in zip (first_column, second_column):
        if q==q
        print (Format (q,a))
```

This code it returning key and values only but not merging a values against 1 duplicated key.

Answer (score 2):

You need  to actually use  the defauldict, appending values.

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
with open('output.csv') as f:
    for line in f: # loop over each line
        spl = line.split() # split , "RAB10   -0.016575" -> ["RAB10","-0.016575"]
        d[spl[0]].append(spl[1]) # append value
print(d)
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'MEF2C': ['-0.019655'], 'RAB10': ['-0.016575'], 'SP2': ['1.24E-01', '-0.18870625', '0.0879425']})
```

If you want the values as float use `d[spl[0]].append(float(spl[1]))` but only if you are sure that all the data is in the same format, if not you would need a `try/except` block.

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
with open("output.csv") as f:
    for line in f:
        spl = line.split()
        try:
            d[spl[0]].append(float(spl[1]))
        except (ValueError,IndexError): # catch lines that don't have at least two elements or the second element is not a float
            continue
```

Comment: Thank u so much. its CSV file containing column. 
its generating error 
"index out of range"  for d[spl[0]].append(spl[1]) piece of code

Comment: do you have empty lines or some lines with only one value? I added a try/except block

Comment: yes I have many non repeating keys (I am using word key:Value in terms of dictionary).leme try hope it will work :(

Comment: after trying "try except" . no output or error returned

Comment: well your file is not in the format you suggest then, `print line` in the loop and add a few lines of what that looks like to your question

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the defaultdict `d` from Padraic Chunningham's answer, it's easy to print it:

```
for key, values in sorted(d.iteritems()):
  values_iter = iter(values)
  print('%s\t%s' % (key, values_iter.next()):
  for value in values_iter:
    print('\t%s' % value)
```

Or, even more compact:

```
for key, values in sorted(d.iteritems()):
  print('%s\t%s' % (key, '\n\t'.join(values)))
```

In Python 3 you need `.items()` instead of `.iteritems()`.