# How to create Python dictionary with multiple 'lists' for each key by reading from .txt file?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a large text file that looks like:

```
1   27  21  22
1   151 24  26
1   48  24  31
2   14  6   8
2   98  13  16
.
.
.
```

that I want to create a dictionary with. The first number of each list should be the key in the dictionary and should be in this format:

```
{1: [(27,21,22),(151,24,26),(48,24,31)],
 2: [(14,6,8),(98,13,16)]}
```

I have the following code (with total points being the largest number in the first column of the text file (ie largest key in dictionary)):

```
from collections import defaultdict

info = defaultdict(list)
filetxt = 'file.txt'
i = 1

with open(filetxt, 'r') as file:
    for i in range(1, num_cities + 1):
        info[i] = 0
    for line in file:
        splitLine = line.split()
        if info[int(splitLine[0])] == 0:
            info[int(splitLine[0])] = ([",".join(splitLine[1:])])
        else:
            info[int(splitLine[0])].append((",".join(splitLine[1:])))
```

which outputs

```
{1: ['27,21,22','151,24,26','48,24,31'],
 2: ['14,6,8','98,13,16']}
```

The reason I want to do this dictionary is because I want to run a for loop through each "inner list" of the dictionary for a given key:

```
for first, second, third, in dictionary:
   ....
```

I cannot do this with my current code because of the slightly different format of the dictionary (it expects 3 values in the for loop above, but receives more than 3), however it would work with the first dictionary format.

Can anyone suggest anyway to fix this?

Comment: Use a defaultdict http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27088835/access-multiple-values-against-1-duplicating-key/27088919#27088919

Comment: can you fix your formatting... your indentation is all over the place.

Comment: better? @AChampion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
result = {}
with open(filetxt, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        # split the read line based on whitespace
        idx, c1, c2, c3 = line.split()

        # setdefault will set default value, if the key doesn't exist and
        # return the value corresponding to the key. In this case, it returns a list and
        # you append all the three values as a tuple to it
        result.setdefault(idx, []).append((int(c1), int(c2), int(c3)))
```

---

Edit: Since you want to the key also to be an integer, you can `map` the `int` function over the split values, like this

```
        idx, c1, c2, c3 = map(int, line.split())
        result.setdefault(idx, []).append((c1, c2, c3))
```

Comment: `from collections import defaultdict` and then `result = defaultdict(list)` will allow to just `result[idx].append(...)`, as a list is guaranteed to be present for any key.

Comment: @9000 I have used defaultdict but it still doesn't give the correct output. Please refer to my updated code.

Answer (score 3):

You are converting your values back to comma separated strings, which you can't use in `for first, second, third in data` - so just leave them as a list `splitLine[1:]` (or convert to `tuple`).
You don't need your initializing `for` loop with a `defaultdict`. You also don't need the conditional checks with `defaultdict` either.

Your code without the superfluous code:

```
with open(filetxt, 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
       splitLine = line.split()
       info[int(splitLine[0])].append(splitLine[1:])
```

One slight difference is if you want to operate on `int`s I would convert up front:

```
with open(filetxt, 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
       splitLine = list(map(int, line.split()))   # list wrapper for Py3
       info[splitLine[0]].append(splitLine[1:])
```

Actually in Py3, I would do:

```
       idx, *cs = map(int, line.split())
       info[idx].append(cs)
```